# Optimize hundreds select queries in JPA

Tags: java, sql, jakarta-ee, jpa

I am using `JPA` and `Facebook` login for my app. After the user has logged in the server checks if each user is in our database by `Facebook` id. I created a `for` loop which execute a `select` query each time. This approach is slow. Is there some better way to make it faster?

The code is

```
for (User friend : friends) {
      User current = userManager.find(friend.facebookId);
If (null != current) { friend.setId(current.getId);}}
```

Comment: Please provide some code snippet of the query and the for loop,

Comment: Please clarify something.  If I am the user and I log on, how many queries get run?

Comment: Hello, I have just put the code. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could execute a single query with an IN instead.  However with caching enabled, querying by id may be the fastest method if the friends are likely to be in the cache.

```
Select f from Friend f where f.id in :ids
```